# vue3 uses pdf.js but displays exceptions

Tags: vuejs3, pdf.js

I downloaded it locally at https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/, the version is the latest, and then unzipped it to the public folder of the project, using the sample code below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuNq6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9W01.png)
However, the browser displays an exception. The following is the display effect and console exception code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALUdE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ9cl.png)

I've tried a lot, but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the source code of pdf.js directly, iframe may be the easiest way to get started.

First install and build with `gulp generic`, see step by step instructions from https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/#getting-the-code.

When build done, there should be a build directory, find the web/index.html in the build directory, all you need is figure out how the index.html works.

Or you can try https://github.com/Priestch/document-viewer, I maintain the library and try to make it easier to get started with pdf.js.